# handleEvent of EventHandler called twice

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I have a listener that implements EventHandler ( org.osgi.service.event.Event ) registered for some events. It seems that my listener's handleEvent getting called twice. I fire the event only once in my code. What could be the osgi framework doing behind the scenes that causes the listener to handle the event twice?
Thanks

Comment: What is the event.topics filter set to? Is the event content exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly but will help you answer it yourself. Just put a breakpoint in the even handler (*handleEvent()*) and see in the stack trace who is calling this method and then go through the logic of it to understand why it is being called twice. Most of the times this is caused by accidentally registering twice to the event publisher

Comment: I had to unregister the listener everytime I create a new one. Apparently the garbage collector doesn't seem to remove the old listener at the right time.

Comment: @svasa : how did you unregistered listener every time ? Please do share code snippet. I am facing same issue. Thanks